# Computing percentages within subtotals

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to compute percentages of a subtotal in one sql statement. This requires using a subquery, but thus far not able to adapt SAS's [example](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n112pviu616u5rn1uileli1b03zb.htm).

Requires 2 steps:

1. Compute subtotal of TotalCargo by LoadArea.
2. Sum the subtotals and divide each LoadArea's subtotal by sum.

Divide subtotal by sum of all the subtotals.

```
 ShipmentID   LoadArea    TotalCargo
 1            BRZ         200000
 2            BRZ         250000
 3            AG          200000
 4            AG          250000 



 End result:
 LoadArea  TotalCargo  Vol_share
 AG        450000      .5
 BRZ       450000      .5
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
SELECT 
  LoadArea, 
  SUM(TotalCargo)AS TotalCargo,
  (SUM(TotalCargo)* 1.0) / 
  (SELECT SUM(TotalCargo) FROM Table1) AS Vol_share
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY LoadArea;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d0d9/3)

This will give you:

```
| LOADAREA | TOTALCARGO | VOL_SHARE |
-------------------------------------
|       AG |     450000 |       0.5 |
|      BRZ |     450000 |       0.5 |
```